# Android recyclerView not fully loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi guys my recyclerView it's not fully loading the adapter data on first run, it will only load after i scroll the recyclerView.
**I think the problem it's something related with the onMeasure of the recyclerView or the height.** i already tried others methods to fix the problem with custom Layout.Managers but no effort.

**My RecyclerView layout:**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_wines"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

**My fragment:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initialization(savedInstanceState);
    }

protected void initialization(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.initialization(savedInstanceState);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_wines);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    loadingProgressBar = (ProgressWheel) getView().findViewById(R.id.loading_progressbar);
    appbarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    backdropTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.backdrop_text_view);

    setUpTabLayout();
    setUpToolbar();
    setUpFragmentCallback();
}

public void onEventMainThread(OnResultEvent resultEvent) {

        if (resultEvent!= null ) {
        setAdapter(resultEvent);
        }
    }

private void setAdapter(OnResultEvent resultEvent) {
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter= new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), resultEvent);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Example:**

[image: On first load]

Comment: Is `initialization` akin to `onCreateView`? You have to find where `setAdapter` is being called.

Comment: I assume you are asking if my initialization it's called in the onCreate, yes it is. if not nothing will show and the app was giving me null pointer exception.

Comment: Ok, my guess is somewhere in your code, `setAdapter` will be called, either in a `addOnScrollListener` code segment or similar touch event.

Comment: @Terence i disagree (correct me if i'am wrong ) because the recyclerView it's setting the adapter and showing data on the beggining, the problem seems to be related with recyclerView loading or recyclerView height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecyclerView does not wrap its content. Assign it a constant value and perhaps you might be able to see the whole result. I had the same problem once. I had to handle the height of the RecyclerView at runtime.

Comment: It was because the CoordinatorLayout doesn't know the height of the imageView inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout, so after i set the height it was alright, but your answer help me to figure out the problem

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am glad that i could help you. Happy Coding!